# Can a standard PVC electrical box be used as a junction box?

Tags: electrical, junction-box

I have one line coming from an outlet and need to branch it to two lines.  Can i use a standard electrical box (blue PVC) as a junction box to branch an electrical line?

Comment: Why can't you put the splice in the outlet box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do what you want, as long as...

- The box remains accessible.
- The box is fitted with a proper cover.

That being said, it may be more appropriate to make the splice in an existing box (assuming the box is large enough for the additional conductors).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough room in an existing box.  I actually wired these this weekend but the circuit isnt hot yet (need to change it from 220 to 110).  I used a single gang pvc box and placed a blank outlet cover over it for now.